# how to remove port number from URL in apache tomcat if connector port is 8081

Tags: java, tomcat, port

I am running multiple instance of tomcat on my linux machine. so there are more than one connector ports for different  instance like 8080,8081,8082. I want to remove port number from URL.

For example :-

**Current url : -** www.sushant.com:8081/
**Needed :-**www.sushant.com/

please suggest me how can i do this.

Thanks.

Comment: i used port 80, but by using this i am able to remove port from only single instance in which i am configure port to 80. but as i mentioned there are many different ports.

Comment: You need a single front-end server operating in reverse proxy mode, which maps external URLs to internal ones, such as mapping `www.sushant.com/service1` to `www.sushant.com:8081`. Google for `nginx reverse proxy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using a proxy on your server. There is a really good tutorial at apache.org, using an Apache Web Server.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

This enables you to connect to your server via port 80, which is not printed in the url bar of your browser.

Answer (score 4):

I saw answer above and struggled a bit, so thought of putting up an example since I was on ubuntu, so I had to change `apache2.conf` file in `/etc/apache2/`
You can find your `apache2.conf` file or `httpd.conf` as per your OS

I added following rules -

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName sushant.com
    ServerAlias www.sushant.com

    ProxyRequests On

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:7777/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:7777/
    </Location>

 </VirtualHost>
 <VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName  sushant.com
    ServerAlias www.sushant.com

    ProxyRequests on

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:8081/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081/
    </Location>

  </VirtualHost>
```

So, now it works both with and without the port.