# tomcat-war file configuration

Tags: tomcat, configuration-files

I have a web-app that is configured to https://www.example.com:8080/login 
I want to hide the port in the URL so my clients can login using https://www.example.com/login URL.
I have configured my app to port 8080 and i don't want to change that , i just want to hide the port being visible in the URL.
Its not a website either, its a war file .
So the problem is , How to hide the Tomcat port number from URL without changing the port???

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584649/how-to-remove-port-number-from-url-in-apache-tomcat-if-connector-port-is-8081

Comment: No, My project is not a website ..its an app only having a single file for deployment ie. app.war file

Comment: **Please tell me where httpd.conf should be placed in my project if i am working in spring tool suite**

Comment: **Also anyone could tell how can i do the port forwarding in firewall for my localhost??**
So that if anyone visits localhost in my network gets directed to localhost:9999